# Combining logical (boolean) expressions in numpy

Tags: numpy, boolean, expression

I want to combine logical expressions but I get an exception:

```
array = np.arange(10)
array > 1 
array([False, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True])
array < 4
array([ True,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False,
       False])
(array > 1 & array < 4)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

What I would expect instead would be a boolean array of length 10 with True value at the indices 2 and 3 --where both conditions are met-- and False elsewhere.

Comment: You should wrap the conditions in parentheses because `&`'s precedence is higher than comparison operators: `(array > 1) & (array < 4)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need numpy's logical_and function.

```
import numpy as np
np.logical_and(array>1, array<4). # [False, False,  True,  True,  False, False,  False, False,  False, False]
```